# Adding the data of a column that has the same ID number mysql

Tags: mysql

Lets say i have this table in mysql

```
ID No. |     Name    |   Contribution | 

  1   |   Pikachu    |         10            
  1     |   Pikachu   |        20           
  2      |   Mewtwo    |         30           
  2     |    Mewtwo      |       40
```

How do i add the contribution that the desired output will be

```
ID No. |    Name     |   Contribution 

1|Pikachu|30               
2|Mewtwo|70
```

Comment: `SUM()` + `GROUP BY ID, Name`

Comment: thank you so much the group by command makes it work thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try grouping result by id and name and use sum to sum up all contributions. Something like:

```
SELECT id, Name, SUM(Contribution) AS Contribution
FROM mytable
GROUP BY id, Name
```

Answer (score 0):

use `group by` and `sum`

```
select ID, Name, sum(contribution) from `table`  group by ID, Name
```